# moving between view controllers without using a segue

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I know should be so simple but how do you move between view controllers on an iPad without using a segue? I have a main menu view controller with a button on it which calls the newViewButton action. I want to open the view controller called MonitorMenu.

```
- (IBAction)newViewButton:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:MonitorMenu  animated:NO];

}
```

It says that MonitorMenu is an unknown interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you declared and your MonitorMenu object and does it inherit from the ViewController class?

Comment: Again - I am sorry if this is so simple - but what do you mean? How do you declare the MonitorMenu object? When I created the MonitorMenu view controller I added the h and m files for a view controller - is that what you mean by inheriting from the ViewController class?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make sure the MonitorMenu ViewController was not inheriting from an NSObject or something.  I will add some code to push the navigation controller.

Comment: @Richard are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Yes - I initially set it up with a segue but I removed it. Might there be something left behind messing things up? The reason for removing it is that I want to run some checks on the page before pushing. The checks are fine but I can't get it to push.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a storyboard, you can do the following:

**1)** select your View Controller you want to push (MonitorMenu) on the storyboard by clicking on the little yellow ball in the bar below the actual view.

[image]

**2)** Then set a set a "Storyboard ID" for it in the "Identity Inspector" tab. (in your case, I'd use "monitorMenuView" or something similar)

[image]

**3)** In the .h file of the view controller you want to 'push' it *from*, import the .h of the class you want to push:

```
#import "MonitorMenu.h"
```

**4)** Then, in your IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)newViewButton:(id)sender {

    MonitorMenu *monitorMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"monitorMenuView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Try `#import "MonitorMenu.h"` in your .m file. Are you getting any warnings when you try this?

Comment: Have you set your custom class in the identity inspector for the view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if your button is not (correctly) connected to the IBAction. I would check that first, then put an NSLog in the IBAction method to see if anything is actually happening.

Comment: Just tried that and put NSLog(@"working"); after the  [self.navigationController pushViewController ... line. It shows "working" in the NSLog so the code is running. Not sure what is wrong. I appreciate your help - don't worry. I'll keep at it. Thanks again.

Comment: Try this `NSLog(@"ViewController: %@", monitorMenuView);` the view controller in the last line of that IBAction, and replace "monitorMenuView" with whatever you called it when you instantiate it. Does it find the correct view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was referring to about declaring your MonitorMenu object:

In your .h file of your current ViewController:

```
           MonitorMenu *_menu;
```

In your .m file of your current ViewController:

```
           //declaring your Monitor Menu object for use
           //then pushing that view onto the stack.
           _menu = [[MonitorMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MonitorMenu" bundle:nil];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:_menu NO];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this and nothing happens when I click the button. I have placed a breakpoint in and the code is run/accessed but it just passes through and the MonitorMenu view does not load.

Comment: Did you import the MonitorMenu.h file in your view controller?

Comment: Do you mean include this in the .m file of the MainMenu? #import "MonitorMenu.h" - yes I have done that.